# Vue Axios: How I get the Link inside a ArrayList

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, axios

I need to get the URL of a picture to show my img :src tag. I tryied:

```
<img class="card-img-top" :src="noticia.Fotos.Link" alt="Card image cap">
```

**This is my HTML:**

```
<div class="col-lg-4" v-for="noticia in noticias">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="card mt-3 col-lg-10 offset-lg-1">
                                    <img class="card-img-top" :src="noticia.Fotos.Link" alt="Card image cap">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h5 class="card-title">{{noticia.Titulo}}</h5>
                                        <p class="card-text text-center">
                                            {{noticia.Descricao}}
                                        </p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

**This is my script:**

```
<script>
        new Vue({
            el: '#noticia',
            data: {
                UnidadeId: "",
                Identificador: "",
                Tipo: "",
            },
            data() {
                return {
                    noticias: [],
                }
            },
            mounted() {
                var self = this
                axios.get('URL', {
                    params: this.axiosParams
                })
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log(response);
                        self.noticias = response.data
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error);
                    })
            },
            computed: {
                axiosParams() {
                    const params = new URLSearchParams();
                    params.append('UnidadeId', '31');
                    params.append('Identificador', '0');
                    params.append('Tipo', '1');
                    return params;
                }
            },
        })
    </script>
```

**The response:**

```
[
    {
        "ItemId": 902,
        "Titulo": "Noticia",
        "Descricao": "Noticia",
        "Data": "/Date(1590593442191)/",
        "QtdeCurtidas": 0,
        "QtdeComentarios": 0,
        "Curtido": false,
        "Observacao": null,
        "Fotos": [
            {
                "FotoId": 1508,
                "Link": "http://agro.aloapp.com.br/Imagens/cVV4S0dINGRESm9IN3IxM2swYXVjZz09/Item/bg_carousel_2.jpg"
            }
        ],
        "Videos": [],
        "IsVideo": false
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to retrieve an element from an array (not an ArrayList) which means you need to specify which element in the array you want. In Javascript, this works by specifying the index of the element in brackets after the array name. If you want the first element, you can do `noticia.Fotos[0].Link`.

Comment: If I try: :src="noticia.Fotos[1].Link", my console return this: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'Link' of undefined". Why?

Comment: In computer science, most of the time arrays start at 0 not 1. In your list, there is a photo at position 0 but not position 1 which is why you get this error